# awk move line up if not matching pattern

Tags: awk

I am new to `awk` and `sed`. I have the following lines and want to move the line up if it does not match pattern.

File:

```
company name
address line
city, state, zip
extra info
company name
address line
city, state, zip
extra info
company name
address line
city, state, zip
extra info
```

... and it goes on like that

want to use pattern matching 'company name' . if the line does not have 'company name' move the line up.

Desired output:

```
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
```

... and continue on

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried collapsing the entire file down to one line and then adding newlines bejust before `company name`?

Answer (score 5):

Here us how to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s"(NR%4?", ":RS),$0}' file
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
```

For every `4` line, use `RS`, else use `,`

---

Or as Jaypal suggested:

```
awk '{ORS=(NR%4?", ":RS)}1' file
```

Comment: or `awk '{ORS=(NR%4?", ":RS)}1' file`

Comment: @jaypal really nice one!!

Answer (score 1):

[paste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_%28Unix%29) is a good tool for this job (assuming you are ok with `,` as a delimiter instead of `,` followed by space)

```
<file paste -d',' - - - -
company name,address line,city, state, zip,extra info
company name,address line,city, state, zip,extra info
company name,address line,city, state, zip,extra info
```

Alternately

```
<file paste -s -d',,,\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/company name/?rs:", "), $0; rs=RS} END{print ""}' file
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this `awk` command also,

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="company"}{ gsub (/\n/,", ");} NR>=2 {sub (/, $/,""); print RS$0}' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
company name
address line
city, state, zip
extra info
company name
address line
city, state, zip
extra info
company name
address line
city, state, zip
extra info

$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="company"}{ gsub (/\n/,", ");} NR>=2 {sub (/, $/,""); print RS$0}' file
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
company name, address line, city, state, zip, extra info
```

Comment: You might want to add using multi-char `RS` makes this GNU `awk` only.

Comment: Avinash's answer worked best. While appreciate the other examples,  since every X lines may not work in my case since the lines separator varies between 3,4,and 5. But here is another situation. In another file I have each of the filelds have quotes in them. example "company name" "address line" etc., which fails with this solution. How do I modify so that the pattern is "company " and not company. Thanks

Comment: @user3616577, you may want to check out Ed Morton's fab solution

Comment: Further to avinash answer, I have another issue. I have another similar file that has a first line that starts serially like 1. somedes #678 followed by lines  address, etc. 2. somemore #763 followed by lines address etc. I need to replace the serialized numbers with DesCode #678 followed by address etc. I have also posted this as a separate question. Thanks again for help